# How to insert a Cookie value into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to insert a cookie value into a button. I can get the cookie to be inserted into a label with the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function()  
{  
    var CookieValue=Cookies.get('utm_source')//get the value from cookie  
    $("#source").text(CookieValue);   
});
```

```
<label id="source" ></label>
```

I need the cookie to be inserted in the following button as a variable for data-csi_utm_source="[]".

```
<button class="cswidget" data-asset-id="2046" data-product-sku="MIN1400B,MIN1400BF,MIN1400BP" data-csi_utm_source="[]" >
    <img class="wtbb" src="https://www.minimizer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/webButton_BuyNow_640x_02-e1637066523728.png" />
</button>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) or [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 0):

you can select button with class and set attribute in following way, i would prrefer to give some unique id to button to access button element.

```
 $(document).ready(function()  {  
    var CookieValue=Cookies.get('utm_source')//get the value from cookie  
        $("#source").text(CookieValue);   
         $( "button.cswidget" ).data( "data-csi_utm_source",  CookieValue);
    
    })
```